# Snapshot-friendly backup / replication of a checked out git repository - without rsync'ing the .git directory

Tags: git, backup, rsync, snapshot

A local checked out git repository should be mirrored to a backup machine, i.e. the `.git` dir and the working tree. On this backup machine filesystem **snapshots** will be taken to allow for easy and *instant* recovery from arbitrary git mishaps[1].

The obvious solution is to use `rsync` and be done, but the regular **git gc** runs create new and different **large .pack** files which do not play nice with snapshotting[2]. This gc option can't easily be changed for the source repo(s). Also this would mean `rsync` traversing everything in the `.git/objects` subfolder, slowing it down.

It would be more elegant to use `git` directly (and just pushing all already-commited work to a bare repository would be easy), but that leaves the worktree. The serverside repo config `receive.denyCurrentBranch = updateInstead` would not work because the worktree might not be clean.

Would something like `git push`'ing, and then `rsync`'ing the worktree plus everything in `.git` *minus* the `objects` subfolder work? Ideally even an in-progress rebase, merge or cherry-pick in  would be replicated. I thought of server side hooks[3] on `post-receive`, but these never see the client worktree state.

1: For things where even git reflog doesn't help, such as the machine dying or `.git` getting corrupted, or just lazy users.

2: E.g. three ~10 line commits and a gc run resulted in ca. 500MB files being transferred.

3: Serverside hooks mean the repo can't be restored via a plain `scp -r`, but that is acceptable.

---

**UPDATE:**

Seems impossible, as e.g. jwz already found out in 2015[j], workarounds:

[..], there have been 3½ suggestions here:

1. Turn off pack files and gc entirely, which will cause small files to
   accumulate for every future change, and will eventually make things 
   get slow. gc.auto 0, gc.autopacklimit 0.
2. Set the maximum pack size to a smaller number, so that no pack file gets too large, and subsequent layers of diffs get bundled into smaller pack files. pack.packSizeLimit.
3. Dissenting opinion on #2: That doesn't do what you think it does, it just slices a single large pack file into N different files with the same bits in them, so you haven't saved anything.
4. If you already have one gigantic pack file, create a .keep file next to it. New pack files will appear but they will be diffs against that saved one, and thus smaller.

j: https://www.jwz.org/blog/2015/05/git-and-backups/

Comment: Have you looked at `git bundle` to create a backup? `git bundle create backup.bundle --all`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that only grabs branches nothing in the work tree, so is the equivalent of `git push bak -f master branch1 branch2 branch3...`

Comment: I'm confused. What's in the work tree that wouldn't be copied?

Comment: Yes, it is a corner case, but the index gets lost, e.g. the progress of a merge conflict resolution or selectively added chunks via `git add --patch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sync the entire working tree state, you'll need to use some system outside of Git. Git intentionally does not sync the working tree state to other systems and can't be made to do so.

However, having said that, I urge you to reconsider whether you want to sync parts of the working tree such as the index. The index is not made to be transferred between machines because it contains information such as inode numbers and file timestamps. In addition, the security model of a Git repository assumes that the working tree is trusted, and the only safe operations that can be made on an untrusted repository are cloning and fetching.

However, if you really want to do so, you can do the push-and-rsync approach. I personally would take the much simpler approach of just using `rsync` and eating the minor performance penalty on repack, since it isn't likely to be that common. By default, `git gc` just creates a new pack with the new objects and doesn't repack all of the existing packs unless there are more than `gc.autoPackLimit` (default 50) packs, so 98% of the time, you'll just rsync a single new pack and delete the old loose objects, plus whatever's in the working tree.

Comment: Thank you for the info that the index stores inodes[1], that of course makes the entire rsync idea unviable.

1: https://github.com/git/git/blob/867b1c1bf68363bcfd17667d6d4b9031fa6a1300/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt#L60

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to *use* git and not to force it to do strange stuff. This means: Use `git push` and `git fetch` into/from a back repository. To also capture the worktree state you can first call something like `git stash push --all` (or only `--include-untracked` instead of `--all`). Then make sure that you mirror the `refs/stash` ref also into the backup repo. Because git has now written objects for everything in the worktree these objects can be transferred into the backup, too.

Comment: Even though it only adds a stash entry (with `--keep-index` of course), that would mean modifying the repo while it is being worked on. And placing large untracked files to a stash (repeatedly, because presumably after the backup the stash is dropped) can take quite some time. Also pushing stashes is ... difficult it seems.

Comment: With `git stash --keep-index` you would not backup the complete state since the content of the index is not stashed then. But `git stash -a; backup; git stash --index` should restore everything.

Comment: @finitegraygreen: Regarding pushing: `git push origin refs/stash:refs/backup/latest` works for me. You can replace `latest` with some timestamp.